# "If variable does not contain" not working

Tags: bash, test

This is my script

```
if [[ ! $url == *.txt ]]
then
exit
fi
```

I have also tried:

```
if [[ ! "$url" == *.txt ]]
then
exit
fi
```

and:

```
if [[ "$url" !== *.txt ]]
then
exit
fi
```

But even though `$url` does contain `*.txt` it still `exit`s?

Comment: What is the exact value of $url?

Comment: Its different every time but something like `/heads/paths/lol.txt`.

Comment: What's the output of `LC_ALL=C printf "%q\n" "$url"`? Does running your script with `bash -x` confirm that it is exiting at that point?

Answer (score 2):

The correct operator for inequality is `!=`. See below:

```
url=/heads/paths/lol.txt
if [[ $url != *.txt ]] ; then echo "does not contain txt"; else echo "contains txt"; fi
```

It gives:

```
contains txt
```

ref: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

```
[ -n "${url%%*.txt}" ] && 
echo "\$url is not null and does not end with the string '.txt'"
```